# Unpacking big-endian encoded port number

Tags: python, networking, endianness

I'm trying to convert a big-endian 2 byte string into a numeric port number. I've already got some code, but I have no idea if it's right:

```
from struct import unpack
def unpack_port(big_endian-port):
   return unpack("!H", big_endian-port)[0]
```

The port (using Python repr() ) is \x1a\xe1, and I get 6881 out of that function.

Is that correct?

Comment: "The form '!' is available for those poor souls who claim they can’t remember whether network byte order is big-endian or little-endian." - A little [struct documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) humor. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, '`!'` is the character that says 'network byte order', and `'H'` says '16-bit unsigned integer', so your code is correct.  6881 is typically a Bittorrent port.

In this case, I believe `'!'` is the correct character.  Since it's a port number, I expect your data is coming from a network.  But, if you knew your data to be big-endian for some other reason, `'>'` might be more appropriate.  They mean the exact same thing and always will.  It's more a matter of commenting your code to indicate intent than any semantic difference.